# deploy jar Java Desktop Application in jdeveloper12c

Tags: deployment, jar, jdeveloper, libs

I have always developed my java NetBeans projects. When I finish my project, and automatically build "dist" folder where the main jar and a "lib" folder containing all the external jar was created. This is done automatically with the NetBeans IDE

Now I'm trying to do a project with jdeveloper 12c Java Desktop Application and try to deploy my project but I have problems with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. I meet several questions:

Can you add the same structure as I said before? That is, a file jar and inside a folder "lib" place the jars using How to do it?

I've seen examples that by New File Group adds refencias, but it really adds to the main jar file (as I see in the size of the file) but not saved in a separate folder.

I do not know if you can help me do this in jdeveloper 12c: Generate a jar file and folder lib with references.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the deployment profile for your project and add all the libraries and files that you need to be included to the JAR you are generating.

Comment: Shay hello, thank you very much for answering. As nobody answered opened a little more specific new question where I bring in more data on this topic. I wish you looked that can be of help to help me. The link is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309747/a-jni-error-has-occurred-jdeveloper12c?noredirect=1#comment48818380_30309747Many thanks

Comment: Shay Hello, I forgot to comment you that within the IDE jdeveloper 12c works perfectly so I do not think the problem is that, the problem is to develop the deployment. When I run the resulting jar by CMD console gives me the error. With jdeveloper 11 had an option to develop the deployment of "Dependency Analysys" in jdeveloper 12c I do not find that option.

I'll post it in this post, thanks again