# A JNI error has occurred (jdeveloper12c)

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm trying to build a Java Desktop Application that uses external libraries.

The project works fine in ide jdeveloper 12c, but when I do the deploy shows me

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, Please chack your installation and try agan. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: orf / icepdf / core ..

I intantando create deploy in project `properties -> Deployment -> Profile Tupe: JAR File -> Main Class: My class -> File Groups -> New Packaging -> Contributors -> Add My jars`.

I have also tried to create the deploy in project `properties -> Deployment -> Profile Tupe: JAR File -> Main Class: My class -> File Groups -> New Libraries` but in both cases I get the error.

EDIT: The code near the error:

```java
public static void setup() throws IOException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("PDF Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    PagePanel panel = new PagePanel(); frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack(); 
    frame.setVisible(true);

    File file = new File("c://test.pdf"); 
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
    FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel(); 
    ByteBuffer buf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
    PDFFile pdffile = new PDFFile(buf);

    PDFPage page = pdffile.getPage(0);
    panel.setClip(null);              
    panel.useZoomTool(true);
    panel.showPage(page);
}
```

Error:

```
C:\JDeveloper\mywork\borrar4\Client\deploy>java -jar archive3.jar
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/p
dfview/PDFPage
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.isCoalesceEventsOverriden(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.Component.checkCoalescing(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at client.PagePanel.<init>(PagePanel.java:77)
        at client.VerPdfSimplePage.setup(VerPdfSimplePage.java:29)
        at client.VerPdfSimplePage$1.run(VerPdfSimplePage.java:57)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 32 more

C:\JDeveloper\mywork\borrar4\Client\deploy>
```

Within the JDeveloper IDE 12c works perfectly, the problem is to develop the deployment. When I run the resulting jar by CMD console gives me the error. With jdeveloper 11 had an option to develop the deployment of "Dependency Analysys" in jdeveloper 12c I do not find that option.

Comment: Please show some code, particularly near where the error messages are talking about

Comment: I tried with this new code library using PDFView to show a simple pdf but I get the same error. The code runs on the ide jdeveloper 12c without error but I am unable to jdeveloper 12c generate a jar with libraries jars packing them in building the project to run through cmd.

Comment: public static void setup() throws IOException {    
JFrame frame = new JFrame("PDF Test");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
PagePanel panel = new PagePanel();
frame.add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
File file = new File("c://test.pdf");
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();
ByteBuffer buf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
PDFFile pdffile = new PDFFile(buf);
PDFPage page = pdffile.getPage(0);
panel.setClip(null);
panel.useZoomTool(true);
panel.showPage(page);        
}

Comment: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\borrar4\Client\deploy>java -jar archive3.jar
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/
dfview/PDFPage
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.isCoalesceEventsOverriden(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component$3.run(Unknown Source)
       ....

Comment: José: I edited the original message and added the code there. If you could edit it once more, and add the complete error message - that would be useful! Don't forget to select the error message part, and then click {} to format it as code.

Comment: Don't post code or computer output in comments. You can see for yourself that it's completely illegible. Edit it into your question. Please also cut and paste the *actual* error message, not your version of it.

Comment: It's important to see the full stack trace, especially any nested exceptions, to debug a NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. Truth does not know how to correctly insert the code, I hope and display ...

I was trying to capture images libraries that I use and also the profile deployment I use, but the forum shows me "You need at least 10 reputation to post images", for now I can not add images to make clear the issue. How this reputation is achieved? Thanks again

Comment: Nobody asked you to post images. Just the code, the stack trace, and the actual message. As text.